# RegEx to enfore 3 digits, padleft

Tags: c#, regex, winforms

I need to create an edit mask for a textbox that only allows digits 0-9 (on it's own, easy enough!), but must always be 3 digits long, and left padded with 0's if a number such as 69 is entered. It is used for a text box holding azimuth values, so I want a bearing such as 78 to show as 078 as the control loses focus.

The following has been suggested in another thread but that is not my requirement:

```
someText = Regex.Replace(someText, @"\d+", n => n.Value.PadLeft(8, '0'));
```

At the moment I do the following in the Validated event, but I have feeling a RegEx edit mask may be more elegant:

```
textBox.Text = textBox.Text.PadLeft(3, '0');
```

Comment: You can use a MaskedTextBox as well with `000` mask.

Comment: Well, until you provide more requirements, I think a masked text box is the cleanest solution.

Comment: Guys, I am sorry!!! Can't believe I was so thick!! Of course, a simple 000 mask is the answer!  Sorry I wasted your time.  Let me go and sulk.now ... :(

Comment: Additionally you can set the`PromptChar` to zero to get the look and feel.

Comment: @juharr: Actually, I created the masked text box with the PromptChar set to 0 before writing the first comment, but did not add that info bit. Got distracted a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`MaskedTextBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx) as well with `000` mask.

> `Mask`
>   Gets or sets the input mask to use at run time.

And [`MaskedTextBox.Mask Property` reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask(v=vs.110).aspx):

> **Masking element**       **Description**
>   `0`                                Digit, required. This element will accept any single digit between 0 and 9.
>   `9`                                Digit or space, optional.
>   `#`                                Digit or space, optional. If this position is blank in the mask, it will be rendered as a space in the Text property. Plus (`+`) and minus (`-`) signs are allowed.

There are more options there.

Also, you can set the `PromptChar` to `0` to make it look nice (as if padded).

**EDIT:**

I have just tried to create a function for TextChanged event, to achieve what you want without masked text box. Just for an exercise:

```
private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var sel = textBox2.SelectionStart;
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox2.Text))
    {
        textBox2.Text = "000";
        return;
    }
    if (sel != 0)
    {
        var symbol_entered = textBox2.Text.Substring(sel - 1, 1);
        if (!Char.IsDigit(symbol_entered.ToCharArray()[0]))
        {
            sel--;
            textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text.Remove(sel, 1);
        }
        else
        { // entered a digit
            if (textBox2.Text.Length == 4 && textBox2.SelectionStart == 4) // last digit entered 
                textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text.Substring(0, 3).PadLeft(3, '0'); // trim it
            else if (textBox2.Text.Length == 4)
                textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text.Remove(sel, 1);
         }
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox2.Text)) // removed the first digit
    {
        textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text.PadLeft(3, '0'); // trim it
        textBox2.SelectionStart = sel;
    }
}
```

Have fun! :)